# SSH hangs without password prompt

Tags: ssh, mac-osx

Just reinstalled OS X and for some reason I now cannot connect to a specific machine on my local network via SSH. I can SSH to other machines on the network without any problems, and other machines can SSH to the problematic one as well.

I'm not sure where to start looking for problems - can anyone point me in the right direction? Here's a dump of a connection attempt:

```
OpenSSH_5.1p1, OpenSSL 0.9.7l 28 Sep 2006
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to 10.0.1.7 [10.0.1.7] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/nwilliams/.ssh/identity type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/nwilliams/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/nwilliams/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_4.5
debug1: match: OpenSSH_4.5 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host '10.0.1.7' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/nwilliams/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-keyex
debug1: No valid Key exchange context
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
```

... at this point it hangs for quite a  while, and then resumes ...

```
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Server not found in Kerberos database

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Server not found in Kerberos database

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information


debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/nwilliams/.ssh/identity
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/nwilliams/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/nwilliams/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Humor me --

Add entries in /etc/hosts for one of the hosts you can't connect to (ie ..

```
 10.0.0.17 Franky
```

If that doesn't do anything .. try editing your ~/.ssh/config

and adding

```
 host *
 PreferredAuthentications publickey,password
```

GSS is a kerberos implementation -- and it seems like its either not finding a domain to toss the host into, or simply needs to be told; yo; don't do that.

Answer (score 4):

I just found the same behaviour with the ssh client OpenSSH_6.0p1lpk running on gentoo, OpenSSL 1.0.1c 10 May 2012 with server OpenSSH_5.5p1 Debian-6+squeeze2, OpenSSL 0.9.8o 01 Jun 2010 running on debian.

In my case, the fix was to remove hpn support on the client and recompile it.

Answer (score 2):

While the thread is a bit old, adding the GSSAPIAuthentication no to my .ssh/config file worked to cure my password prompt hang.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you manage to login after all the delays. Put this in your `~/.ssh/config` file:

```
Host *
    GSSAPIAuthentication no
```

Comment: I'm actually not able to login, but I am fairly certain that has more do with the whole process timing out before it gets to the "password" authentication method.